# Keeping type with apply

Tags: r

When I use `apply` it seems the type is always cast to `character` - I want to react to columns differently depending on the type, is there any way to keep the type or an analogous function that does?

```
calculate_stats = function(data, divideby){
  print(typeof(data)) # Always prints character!
}

get_result_table = function(data, divideby){
  apply(data, 2, calculate_stats, divideby = divideby)
}

get_result_table(iris, iris$Species)
```

Comment: `apply` will implicitly coerce your data into a `matrix` (see `?apply`), which only allows single mode datatypes. Since `iris$Species` is a factor, all columns will be coerced into character columns.

Comment: I saw that - just wondering if there was some magic variable, as there sometimes is. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Not sure, but see my `sapply` answer below...

Comment: vapply can specify the type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to my comment above, if you define

```
get_result_table = function(data, divideby) {
    sapply(data, calculate_stats, divideby = divideby)
}
```

you get

```
get_result_table(iris, iris$Species)
#[1] "double"
#[1] "double"
#[1] "double"
#[1] "double"
#[1] "integer"
#Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species
#    "double"     "double"     "double"     "double"    "integer"
```

Perhaps this is more what you expect?

Comment: This is - thank you! Is it possible to get the column name from the `calculate_stats` function?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you after a named character vector with the column datatypes?

Comment: Exactly (Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width Species) - is the only workaround to pass a sequence?

Comment: If you remove the `print` command from `calculate_stats`, `sapply` will return a named vector of datatypes. So just like in my answer above but without the first 5 lines. You can then store/print the output of `get_result_table`.

Comment: `sapply()` is _absolutely not_ guaranteed to preserved type. `vapp()` or one of the `purrr::map_*()` function will do that.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I never made that claim.

Comment: _"I want to react to columns differently depending on the type, is there any way to keep the type or an analogous function that does?"_ i.e. this doesn't solve this requirement

Comment: In this particular case `sapply` *does in fact* "keep the type" as I demonstrate. So it *does* solve OP's requirement. I'm not sure what your peeve is, you've already given a more general alternative. If you want to have the last word, it's all yours.

Answer (score 0):

`colwise` from the `plyr` package does exactly this.